# Webserver accessible only from CloudFlare?

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, denial-of-service

I wan't to avoid getting DDoSed as much as possible i can, so i thought if it's possible to set my web server to communicate only through CloudFlare. Any request from another source will be rejected, except myself of course. 
Any hope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly. If you set up Cloudflare first and change your DNS settings to point to CF.

Once confirmed to be working, you will need to configure your server to only accept connections from it. You will, of course, need some other connections too so make sure you don't lock yourself out - add an allowance for whatever network you normally connect from so you get direct access.

Easiest way to prevent connections assuming you are running the server from a VPS is to use Linux IPTABLES to prevent any connections except the two above. There are many tutorials for IPTABLES on the web.

By the way, this is not a sure fire way to avoid DDOS since there are a number of DDOS methods, however it is probably about as good as it gets without the use of a protected data centre and enterprise or carrier class WAN.